# Postfix: How to use reject_sender_login_mismatch when using MySQL virtual users?

Tags: postfix, sasl, smtp-auth

I want to force senders to use an envelope sender address that's identical to the SASL login username. From [the Postfix SASL README](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) I see I should list, in the `smtpd_sender_login_maps` option, a hash table that has two identical columns and list all valid e-mails, and also specify `reject_sender_login_mismatch` in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.

But I have MySQL virtual domains and users table, and things aren't like that. For users, I have the following:

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
```

Where the contents of `mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf` is like this:

```
user = dbuser
password = dbpass
dbname = mail
query = SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1),'/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',1),'/') FROM users WHERE email='%s'
hosts = dbhost
```

This returns something like `domainname.com/userpart/` for email `userpart@domainname.com`. That's not listed in the allowed formats in [the Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps).

Should I change the query for a different output format or can I just add `reject_sender_login_mismatch` to `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` and the restriction will work? I'm trying the following options:

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_sender_login_mismatch, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_sender_login_mismatch, reject_unknown_sender_domain, permit
```